# Why isn't there the Edit button in User Profile when we navigate to meta.tex.stackexchange.com?

Tags: feature-request

Why isn't there the `Edit` button in `User Profile` when we navigate to meta.tex.stackexchange.com?

Is it a bug?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your meta profile is not independent of the main user profile, but just a copy of it. You only can edit your main profile and the changes will be synchronized to meta after a short while. Same counts for the reputation.

Comment: However their view counters are independent.

Comment: What about placing an edit button in the user profile of meta and linking it to edit on the main user profile?

Comment: @N.N.: We moderators don't have direct influence on the web layout. You would have to request that on http://meta.stackexchange.com and then it would be for all SX sites.

Comment: I see, thanks. I just registered so I'm new to all this.

Comment: @N.N.: Sure, no problem. Note that there is a "main user" link below the user icon on the meta profile which allows you to switch quickly to the main user profile.